# Japanese Self-Evaluation -- Let's Get Critical!

Tags: discussion, quality-evaluation

You love your site and we love your site, but there is a whole world of people out there who might not even know it exists. When they do find it, their first impression will either scare them away or keep them around. Given this, let's take a hard look at the questions and answers here and make sure newcomers see the site at its best!

Below you'll find ten questions randomly selected from this site. What do you think about each of them and their answers? Are they the best they can be or can they be improved? Would they look interesting and inviting to an outsider or are they a little embarrassing?

Upvote the corresponding post here on meta when we're awesome. Downvote when our content just isn't quite up to par.

Oh, and do comment to let everyone know your thoughts and take part in this conversation. :)

**Note:** This evaluation will close on **10 October 2012**. Please get your comments in by then!

Comment: As an aside: よろしくお願いします~!

Comment: Thanks for your help, everyone!

Comment: I don't know if you caught this, or if it happened here (I was away for this eval), but apparently the [vote fraud script is incorrectly removing multiple downvotes from some evaluations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150180/).  Jeff posted a [workaround](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150180/the-vote-fraud-script-breaks-legitimate-polling-questions-a-serial-downvoters#comment434519_151464) where you disassociate the owner from the answer posts.

Comment: @Troyen yeah, Anna and I saw that. We're going to try and make sure we do that moving forward.

Answer (score 9):

[How 「えい」 should be pronounced in the words like 英語, 先生, etc?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6572/how-%e3%80%8c%e3%81%88%e3%81%84%e3%80%8d-should-be-pronounced-in-the-words-like-%e8%8b%b1%e8%aa%9e-%e5%85%88%e7%94%9f-etc)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Question was edited -- and now this post is, too!

Comment: There is a slight mismatch here between a very low-level basic question, and an extremely informative (but very technical) answer by taylor. With that said, it's an excellent landing page for someone seriously interested in the language.

Comment: @jkerian I perfectly agree. Maybe a little too tl;dr for the casual reader though?

Comment: [amused] At first glance, I felt even the "short" answer was too long. Improved formatting will help.

Comment: I took a crack at reformatting the short answer.

Answer (score 8):

[How did 家, 手, and 士 come to be included in the names of professions?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6605/how-did-%e5%ae%b6-%e6%89%8b-and-%e5%a3%ab-come-to-be-included-in-the-names-of-professions)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: :( A case of answer-in-question-comment syndrome.

Answer (score 8):

[Difference between Fire : 火【ひ】and 火事【かじ】?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6514/difference-between-fire-%e7%81%ab%e3%80%90%e3%81%b2%e3%80%91and-%e7%81%ab%e4%ba%8b%e3%80%90%e3%81%8b%e3%81%98%e3%80%91)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: :( A case of answer-in-question-comment syndrome.

Comment: @ento we seem to get a lot of those on this site...

Answer (score 5):

[The difference between 初めて, 最初に and 最初](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6535/the-difference-between-%e5%88%9d%e3%82%81%e3%81%a6-%e6%9c%80%e5%88%9d%e3%81%ab-and-%e6%9c%80%e5%88%9d)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: There are some answers here, but it seems like they could be made a bit more authoritative.

Answer (score 5):

[What is よ doing as a connector before a comma?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6594/what-is-%e3%82%88-doing-as-a-connector-before-a-comma)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Answer (score 3):

[Making sense of the N1にN2 construction (「パンにバター」＝「パンにバターをぬる」）](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6600/making-sense-of-the-n1%e3%81%abn2-construction-%e3%80%8c%e3%83%91%e3%83%b3%e3%81%ab%e3%83%90%e3%82%bf%e3%83%bc%e3%80%8d%ef%bc%9d%e3%80%8c%e3%83%91%e3%83%b3%e3%81%ab%e3%83%90%e3%82%bf%e3%83%bc%e3%82%92%e3%81%ac%e3%82%8b%e3%80%8d%ef%bc%89)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: This is not the best introduction to the community, but this is only because the question was fundamentally the result of misunderstanding a grammar point. There's nothing *wrong* with it, per se, it's just not a great advertisement.

Answer (score 3):

[Where does the word キレる come from?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6519/where-does-the-word-%e3%82%ad%e3%83%ac%e3%82%8b-come-from)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: The combination of the two answers provides very good coverage. One covers what it means, why it's spelled in katakana+hiragana, and how to use it.  The other discusses the probable origin of this form.

Answer (score 3):

[Spotting the N1 に N2 construction (eg パンにバター）](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6596/spotting-the-n1-%e3%81%ab-n2-construction-eg-%e3%83%91%e3%83%b3%e3%81%ab%e3%83%90%e3%82%bf%e3%83%bc%ef%bc%89)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: Is the Nx notation familiar to most people?

Answer (score 3):

[What is 方 used for (when attached to a た-verb)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6525/what-is-suffix-%e6%96%b9-used-for-when-attached-to-a-%e3%81%9f-verb)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

Comment: 方 isn't a suffix, so the title might be a little confusing for someone who actually does know the answer. Edited the title accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

[Different conventions for animal meat](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6629/different-conventions-for-animal-meat)

What do you think about this question and its answers? Vote and comment to let everyone know.

[Edit!]

Comment: The existing answer doesn't provide a good explanation.  The existing comments on the answer already make this observation.  The answer is much more like a comment and less like an answer.

Comment: @Peter: I kindof disagree. The answer actually does give you the pattern, it's just not a convenient rule you can use for any given situation. You have to know the etymology. I'll edit it to make it more explicit, but the information has been there since the original answer.

Comment: @jkerian - the updated version is much clearer and easier to follow.

Comment: @Peter I have to agree with jkerian. It's unfortunate, but a consequence of this being a language Q&A site is that there won't always be a convention. Or at least, one as strict as the asker is looking for. This is one of those cases.

Comment: @phoenixheart6 - my comment says that the answer didn't provide a good explanation, whether there was a pattern or not I felt that this was true.  This was a comment based on the OLD answer.  I posted a new comment shortly after jkerian updated his answer saying that it was much better.  Unfortunately my -1 is already locked in and I can't remove it :(

Comment: Maybe @Aarthi could modify the answer so I could remove my down vote since this question has been modified.

Comment: @Peter Done! :)

Comment: @Peter After looking at the original answer in the edit history, yea, you're right.